# Monerod is syncing 1 block at a time seemingly backwards?

Tags: monerod, synchronization

Monerod is syncing super slowly since the last week or so. It goes one block at a time and each block can take a couple of minutes.

I am on the 10.3.1 and everything was working fine before.

Edit: Sorry but I didn't realize, monerod is ADDING a block or a couple during sync every couple of minutes which means it never finishes. Below is my output:

```
2017-06-08 19:38:37.022 [P2P3]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1115    
You are now synchronized with the network. You may now start monero-wallet-cli.
Use the "help" command to see the list of available commands.
2017-06-08 19:38:40.142 [P2P3]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293 [62.210.254.196:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1322313 -> 1328131 [Your node is 5818 blocks (8 days) behind]
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2017-06-08 19:43:32.596 [P2P0]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293 [89.143.132.235:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1322313 -> 1328132 [Your node is 5819 blocks (8 days) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2017-06-08 19:45:38.025 [P2P4]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293 [81.169.173.184:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1322313 -> 1328134 [Your node is 5821 blocks (8 days) behind]
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2017-06-08 19:47:31.496 [P2P1]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293 [23.245.144.101:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1322313 -> 1328135 [Your node is 5822 blocks (8 days) behind]
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2017-06-08 19:48:42.983 [P2P9]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293 [45.76.178.233:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1322313 -> 1328137 [Your node is 5824 blocks (8 days) behind]
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2017-06-08 19:55:22.627 [P2P9]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293 [217.182.171.167:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1322313 -> 1328141 [Your node is 5828 blocks (8 days) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2017-06-08 19:55:31.754 [P2P3]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293 [138.201.235.152:20001 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1322313 -> 1328142 [Your node is 5829 blocks (8 days) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2017-06-08 19:59:23.678 [P2P6]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293 [217.182.171.167:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1322313 -> 1328144 [Your node is 5831 blocks (8 days) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2017-06-08 20:07:38.754 [P2P4]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293 [158.69.43.253:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1322313 -> 1328145 [Your node is 5832 blocks (8 days) behind]
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2017-06-08 20:12:25.446 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293 [91.121.69.93:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1322313 -> 1328149 [Your node is 5836 blocks (8 days) behind]
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2017-06-08 20:22:39.661 [P2P4]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293 [23.245.144.101:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1322313 -> 1328150 [Your node is 5837 blocks (8 days) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
exit
Stop signal sent
2017-06-08 20:23:50.801 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:80 p2p net loop stopped
2017-06-08 20:23:50.845 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:78 Stopping core rpc server...
2017-06-08 20:23:50.845 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/daemon.cpp:145   Node stopped.
2017-06-08 20:23:50.845 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:90 Deinitializing rpc server...
2017-06-08 20:23:50.845 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:90 Deinitializing p2p...
2017-06-08 20:23:50.847 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:89    Deinitializing core...
2017-06-08 20:23:50.891 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:77    Stopping cryptonote protocol...
2017-06-08 20:23:50.891 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:81    Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
```

---

#### SECOND PART:

```
2017-06-10 22:27:17.842 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293 [23.245.144.101:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1324636 -> 1329663 [Your node is 5027 blocks (6 days) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2017-06-10 22:27:37.008 [P2P6]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:745    [181.41.201.170:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-10 22:27:37.008 [P2P0]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:794    [181.41.201.170:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
2017-06-10 22:28:49.785 [P2P9]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:745    [89.177.28.23:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-10 22:28:49.785 [P2P6]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:794    [89.177.28.23:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
2017-06-10 22:29:43.495 [P2P0]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:745    [136.62.94.192:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-10 22:29:43.495 [P2P6]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:794    [136.62.94.192:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
2017-06-10 22:29:57.319 [P2P0]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:745    [173.216.145.253:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-10 22:29:57.320 [P2P6]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:794    [173.216.145.253:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
2017-06-10 22:30:06.332 [P2P4]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:819    [91.191.236.234:18080 OUT] COMMAND_TIMED_SYNC invoke failed. (-3, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_DESTROYED)
2017-06-10 22:30:06.332 [P2P4]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:819    [91.191.236.234:18080 OUT] COMMAND_TIMED_SYNC invoke failed. (-3, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_DESTROYED)
2017-06-10 22:30:23.053 [P2P1]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:819    [109.173.104.175:18080 OUT] COMMAND_TIMED_SYNC invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-10 22:30:23.053 [P2P4]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:819    [158.69.43.253:18080 OUT] COMMAND_TIMED_SYNC invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-10 22:30:23.054 [P2P1]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:819    [109.173.104.175:18080 OUT] COMMAND_TIMED_SYNC invoke failed. (-3, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_DESTROYED)
2017-06-10 22:30:23.054 [P2P4]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:819    [158.69.43.253:18080 OUT] COMMAND_TIMED_SYNC invoke failed. (-3, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_DESTROYED)
2017-06-10 22:30:23.054 [P2P3]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:819    [192.99.33.78:18080 OUT] COMMAND_TIMED_SYNC invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-10 22:30:23.054 [P2P3]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:819    [23.245.144.101:18080 OUT] COMMAND_TIMED_SYNC invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-10 22:30:23.054 [P2P3]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:819    [23.245.144.101:18080 OUT] COMMAND_TIMED_SYNC invoke failed. (-3, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_DESTROYED)
2017-06-10 22:30:25.896 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1004    [23.245.144.101:18080 OUT]  Synced 1324836/1329663
2017-06-10 22:30:25.898 [P2P7]  ERROR   net contrib/epee/include/net/levin_protocol_handler_async.h:258 [23.245.144.101:18080 OUT] [levin_protocol] -->> start_outer_call failed
2017-06-10 22:31:00.224 [P2P5]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:745    [91.191.236.234:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-10 22:31:00.385 [P2P2]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:794    [91.191.236.234:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
2017-06-10 22:31:13.100 [P2P3]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:745    [136.62.94.192:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-10 22:31:13.100 [P2P2]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:794    [136.62.94.192:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
2017-06-10 22:31:47.676 [P2P1]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:745    [104.223.103.222:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-10 22:31:47.676 [P2P2]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:794    [104.223.103.222:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
2017-06-10 22:32:00.924 [P2P2]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:745    [91.191.236.234:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-10 22:32:00.924 [P2P9]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:794    [91.191.236.234:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
2017-06-10 22:32:03.473 [P2P1]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:819    [192.99.33.78:18080 OUT] COMMAND_TIMED_SYNC invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-10 22:32:08.348 [P2P0]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:745    [158.69.43.253:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-10 22:32:08.348 [P2P9]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:794    [158.69.43.253:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
2017-06-10 22:32:17.106 [P2P5]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:819    [192.99.33.78:18080 OUT] COMMAND_TIMED_SYNC invoke failed. (-3, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_DESTROYED)
2017-06-10 22:32:20.505 [P2P1]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:745    [173.216.145.253:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-10 22:32:20.506 [P2P9]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:794    [173.216.145.253:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
2017-06-10 22:32:26.471 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293 [138.201.235.152:20001 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1324836 -> 1329668 [Your node is 4832 blocks (6 days) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2017-06-10 22:33:10.840 [P2P4]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:745    [58.18.7.251:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-4, LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT)
2017-06-10 22:33:10.840 [P2P9]  ERROR   net.p2p src/p2p/net_node.inl:794    [58.18.7.251:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
exit
Stop signal sent
2017-06-10 22:33:21.454 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:80 p2p net loop stopped
2017-06-10 22:33:21.461 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:78 Stopping core rpc server...
2017-06-10 22:33:21.461 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/daemon.cpp:145   Node stopped.
2017-06-10 22:33:21.461 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:90 Deinitializing rpc server...
2017-06-10 22:33:21.461 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:90 Deinitializing p2p...
2017-06-10 22:33:21.470 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:89    Deinitializing core...
2017-06-10 22:33:21.542 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:77    Stopping cryptonote protocol...
2017-06-10 22:33:21.542 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:81    Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
```

Answer (score 6):

That sounds remarkably normal since Monero's block target is 2 minutes. So you'd be expected to receive a block every two minutes on average.

Try running `status` in monerod. You'll be given the local blockchain height, and the highest known blockchain height from peers. If those match, then you've synced to the tip, and are receiving new blocks shortly after they're mined, as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually made a mistake in my OP. When synching the chain, I get up to 8 days behind with synchronization going normally, then all of a sudden it doesn't synch one block at a time, but ADDS one block every couple of minutes. So synching no longer works and I am going BACKWARDS 1 block with every new block mined. It has me stumped. I deleted everything, and re-installed from the beginning. I downloaded the blockchain from scratch and....when I got to 8 days, the same thing again! Would you like a screenshot?

Comment: I edited the post and posted my output. Sorry for the confusion, and I would have said this in my previous comment, but it wouldn't let me edit after 5 mins.

Comment: Try adding `--block-sync-size 20`. If that does not work, start again with `--log-level 1`, and see what problems are reported when trying to add those blocks.

Comment: Setting block sync size to 20 worked! I am trying to understand why the default setting of 200 is not working for me now as it worked fine from block 0 all the way up until 8 days or so ago. I ran it in debug like you said and posted the output in the OP. It seems the handshake is failing. Do you know why and what I can do about it? Thanks.

Comment: This is due to a timeout, which can trigger if you're syncing from a peer where you can't get 200 blocks within 2 minutes or so. See https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2073 for a fix.

Comment: Ah, ok. I checked the conversations on Git and it seems hyc has done a patch but is still in testing. Will it be in the next release?

Comment: If it's waiting for testing, then that's a perfect time to test it ? And it'll likely be in next release, yes.